# AWS Dynamodb ContinuousBackupsUnavailableException

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, backup

I'm trying to backup my DynamoDB table that was originally created over a year ago using DynamoDBs new "backup" feature.  However when I go to create the backup, I get the following error message:

```
Backups are being enabled for the table: prod-supercoolsoftware-stuff. Please
retry later (Service: AmazonDynamoDBv2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: 
ContinuousBackupsUnavailableException; Request ID: 
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

However, when I backup a table made just yesterday on the same account in the same region, it works.

Will my table eventually be able to be backed up?  Or do I need to figure out how to create a new table and migrate the data over to it (yuck!)?

Edit:  backups are now enabled for my tables 12/26/17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think its worth just waiting a while and trying again in the next few days and weeks. According to the AWS docs the exception means [Backups have not yet been enabled for this table.](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_CreateBackup.html) So it sounds like an expected situation rather than a functional exception.

AWS have indicated the backup feature is being [rolled out incrementally](https://aws.amazon.com/dynamodb/backup-restore/)

> On-Demand Backup is being rolled out to US East (N. Virginia), US East
>   (Ohio), US West (Oregon), EU (Ireland) regions starting today, and
>   will be completed for all tables in the coming weeks.

The above announcement is not dated but im pretty sure it was from last week (late Nov 2017).

Although the statement doesn't specify any details, it sounds like even within those regions, individual tables may get the feature at different times.

Answer (score 1):

It takes time for AWS to allow you to enable `Point In Time Recovery` after a table is created, so our solution is to add retry logic with a delay, because it looks like expected behavior for DynamoDB.

Here is the example on Kotlin for AsyncDynamoDbClient and WebFlux:

```
 Mono.defer {
   client.updateContinuousBackups(updateContinuousBackupsRequest)
         .toMono()
}
 .retryBackoff(5, Duration.ofMillis(100))
```

Comment: Please use correct indentation for code blocks

Answer (score 0):

Enable backups on the old table and wait for them to be enabled. For new tables, backups are enabled by default.